# Xamarin Forms Grid in a TableView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, tableview, xamarin.forms

I am creating a financial app and need to show a table with section headers and many grids.

In the attached screenshot I am almost there. I need the first column to Left align (start) and the rows to be about double their default height.

```
        var content = new TableView
        {
            Intent = TableIntent.Data,
            Root = new TableRoot("Performance"),
            BackgroundColor = Color.Green
        };
        content.Root.Add(GetTableSection("Monthly", Model.Monthly);

    .................

    private TableSection GetTableSection(string title, List<PerformanceRow> performanceRows)
    {
        TableSection section = new TableSection()
        {
            Title = title 
        };

        foreach (var row in performanceRows)
        {
            Grid grid = new Grid
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HeightRequest = 100,  //?????????
                BackgroundColor = Color.Red,
                ColumnDefinitions =
                {
                    new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(.3, GridUnitType.Star)},
                    new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(.3, GridUnitType.Star)},
                    new ColumnDefinition {Width = new GridLength(.3, GridUnitType.Star)},

                } 
            };

            //First Row
            grid.Children.Add(new Label {Text = row.Title, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start}, 1, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label {Text = "Market Value"}, 2, 0);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label {Text = row.MarketValue.ToString("C"), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End}, 3, 0);

            //Second Row
            grid.Children.Add(new Label {Text = " "}, 1, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label {Text = "Return"}, 2, 1);
            grid.Children.Add(new Label {Text = row.ReturnRate.ToString("C"), HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End}, 3, 1);
            section.Add(new ViewCell()
            {
                View = grid,
                Height = 100 //??????????
            });
        }
        return section;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

Set the UnevenRows to true for the tableview, then the table intent to rows